# Overwriting MUI with scss

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

I'm working on a React project that uses MUI and Sass. Currently there are multiple scss-files full of `!important` to overwrite the MUI styles with sass. I tried to fix this by removing the `!important`'s and adding:

```
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline'

<CssBaseline />
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
*** component tree here ***
</StyledEngineProvider>
```

as suggested here: [Issue with @Mui and modularized scss competing intermittently. How to consistently override @mui default styling with scss modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842773/issue-with-mui-and-modularized-scss-competing-intermittently-how-to-consistent)

Which seemed to work at first but stops working when you focus on a component. For example this button turns white with a blue border when hovered over:

scss

```
.button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-transform: none;
}

.go-button {
    @extend .button;
    background-color: grey;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
```

reactjs

```
<Button
   className="go-button"
   variant="outlined"
   onClick={handleClick}
>
   Go
</Button>
```

We are not using modules or makeStyles. What would be the best way to overwrite MUI without the `!important`'s?

Comment: Please add an example of the styles that aren't working along with a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Unfortunately I don't have time to learn how to use code sandbox and make one right now, but I added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default styles for many MUI components will include some styles for specific states like `:hover`, `.Mui-focused` that have a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the styles of the default state. When overriding those styles you need to use the same specificity.

For instance, `Button` has [default styles specific to hover](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.10.12/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L89), so you will need to specify style overrides for the hover state.

For example, here's one possible way to define your button styles:

```
.button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-transform: none;
}

.go-button {
  @extend .button;
  background-color: grey;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
.go-button:hover {
  @extend .go-button;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

[image: Edit scss button styles]

Answer (score -1):

According to my knowledge experience, you must use styled-components with MUI because they have a better pair rather then SCSS, with better pair you have better performance of the website & with styled-components you can easily modify the changes of MUI.

[Visit this link for advanced usage](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced)

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use SCSS with MUI. Using styled-components doesn't necessarily make it any easier to override styles, it just changes the syntax and allows you to manage the styles in your component code. Using styled-components definitely will not improve performance of the website compared to SCSS.

Comment: I feel awkward that MUI customization is mainly available with styled-components. Javascript codes are messed up, and maintaining global Sass strategies is hard because of it. I would not use MUI for the next project.